# Way of counting (non. Garbage collected) objects

Tags: c#, debugging, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling

I have a memory leak in a production app. The app will run fine and then suddenly the memory will nose dive. Due to reasons beyond my control, I can not attach a normal memory profiler (like dotMemory).

**Is there some way, from within my application code, that I can periodically count the number of objects that are currently live inside the app?**

Comment: have you considered taking a memory dump and examining it?

Comment: Just get WinDbg, grab a dump from the process and examine it. Be prepared to restart the process and try to take the memory dump when memory use is still under 2-3 GB (otherwise all tools will take ages to analyze it).

Comment: If WinDbg is too steep to learn try DebugDiag first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately for the same reasons I can't attach a profiler, I can't get a memory dump (A combination of technical reasons, security, uptime requirements, and a good dose of politics). I have tried...

Comment: Have you used the new .NET Object Allocation Tool in Visual Studio? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/net-object-allocation-tool-performance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question cannot be answered with a blanket answer, however, you can try one of the following:

- Pause/freeze your Application and create a memory dump of the process (assuming you are using Windows, you can use the Task Manager's Details pane and right-click any process and use the command `Create dump file`.
   You may then open the dump file using Visual Studio, which can automatically re-create the memory heap.
- Use Visual Studio's own Memory Profiler. It can examine all heap objects, their size, count, type, etc. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022 for more information.
- <s>Use external profiling tools</s> Nevermind, you said that that is not possible
- Implement your own object counter (assuming you are counting your own objects):

  ```
  // a dataset of all object informations you want to store
  public record ObjectInfo(
      DateTime DateTimeAllocated,
      Type Type,
      ...
  )

  public abstract class profilable_object
      : object
  {
      public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<profilable_object, ObjectInfo> Heap = new();


      public profilable_object() =>
          Heap[this] = new(DateTime.Now, GetType(), ...);

      ~profilable_object() => Heap.TryRemove(this, out _);
  }
  ```

  Then make **ALL OF YOUR CLASSES** inherit from `profilable_object`. You can then inspect your "heap" using the static field `profilable_object.Heap`.
  Take a look at [this file from the GitHub project "sharplab.io"](https://github.com/ashmind/SharpLab/blob/721fbeffe4467f8e2875733d5a4115f99eef890f/source/Container/Runtime/MemoryBytesInspector.cs#L15) on how to get the size and layout of a heap object.

  #### Needless to say, this solution will take quite a performance hit and should only be used as a last resort.